# Carry user info from one razor page to another using cookies

Tags: c#, cookies, razor-pages

Currently, I have a form which asks for the primary key and when the user submits it redirects it to another page. I want to display the record on another page. I have tried creating a cookie but it isnt working. When I print the string that should have been stored in cookie it shows nothing.

Comment: you should provide a code example to show your approach.

Comment: any specific reason to go for cookies?

Answer (score 0):

You can carry information from one page to other, for example by parametrize your redirect methods in code-behind:

```
// Page A
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync() 
{
 //...
 RedirectToPage("PageB", new { PrimaryKey = value});
}

// Page B
public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync(string PrimaryKey)
{
 // use your key
}
```